# unable to save sharedPreference state

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> I am using a Toggle Button as favorite in my RecyclerView Adapter
>
> EDIT : The below solution worked, but now when I favorite one and restart the App, then all of the buttons get favorited and this the same for unfavorite case also, Please Provide a solution
>
> Here is the code :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyModel myModel = myModelList.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(myModel.getImage());
        holder.textView.setText(myModel.getText());
        holder.toggle_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean isFavourite = readStae();
                if (isFavourite) {
                    holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav);
                    isFavourite = false;
                    saveStae(isFavourite);
                } else {
                    holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unfav);
                    isFavourite = true;
                    saveStae(isFavourite);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myModelList.size();
    }
    private void saveStae(boolean isFavourite) {
        SharedPreferences aSharedPreferenes = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor aSharedPreferenesEdit = aSharedPreferenes
                .edit();
        aSharedPreferenesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite);
        aSharedPreferenesEdit.commit();
    }

    private boolean readStae() {
        SharedPreferences aSharedPreferenes = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "Favourite", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return aSharedPreferenes.getBoolean("State", false);
    }
}
```

> When I restart the App, the Favorited button is not there.
>
> What am I doing Wrong, please explain the solution, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `readState()` inside the Click Listener, so on `onBindViewHolder`, it will not execute that method. you need to change your code like this.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyModel myModel = myModelList.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(myModel.getImage());
    holder.textView.setText(myModel.getText());
    boolean isFavourite = readStae();
     if (isFavourite) {
        holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav);
     } else {
        holder.toggle_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unfav);
    } }
```

and then apply click listener insidie the ViewHolder Class.

Comment: Good catch! Not anyone could see it.

Comment: Now, if i favorite one, and then restart the App, then all buttons are favorited and this is also the same for unfavorited case also. what to do ?

Comment: aSharedPreferenesEdit.putBoolean("State", isFavourite); this line is saving true for all buttons, change the "State" text with Button text or any thing else which is related to that button.